# What happens to the main part of your soul after making a Horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

So when you die like Voldemort did with horcruxes on earth, where does the main part of your soul go that was in your body?
 Does it just float around like a ghost, or exist in that state of Limbo such as when Harry was "killed" in the forbidden forest. From my understanding it would need to possess someone to move around, so what happened when Voldemort first died, was it just stuck there? This also means it has to exist on earth, not in the limbo state right? I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find out how it exists without a body.
  Final question, which i'm sure will be answered once i understand where and how the soul exists; what about this makes it so miserable to exist that most wizards never do this?

Comment: The murdering people aspect of horcrux creation is probably enough to put most people off. Then there's the fact that you need to be immensely powerful and willing to tear your living soul into pieces with rare and highly dangerous magics. It's not for everyone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It remains on Earth

When Voldemort was ripped from his body, he remained on Earth, and traveled in spirit form to the forests of Albania:

> “I remember only forcing myself, sleeplessly, endlessly, second by
> second, to exist.... **I settled in a faraway place, in a forest, and
> I waited**...."
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

Without a body, the soul is a powerless, *agonizing* state:

> "Nevertheless, I was as powerless as the weakest creature alive, and
> without the means to help myself . . . for I had no body, and every
> spell that might have helped me required the use of a wand...."
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*
>
> ---
>
> “I remember only forcing myself, sleeplessly, endlessly, second by
> second, to exist. . . ."
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

It does not float around like a ghost: it is in some ways *less* than a ghost:

> "I was less than spirit, less than the meanest ghost . . . but still,
> I was alive."
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

**When in spirit form, Voldemort did not need to possess someone to move around.**

> "Oh, he seemed the very chance I had been dreaming of . . . for he was
> a teacher at Dumbledore’s school . . . he was easy to bend to my will
> ... **he brought me back to this country, and after a while, I took
> possession of his body**, to supervise him closely as he carried out my
> orders."
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

The order of things in this sentence indicates that Quirrell brought him back to England *before* Voldemort possessed Quirrell. Beside, if Voldemort had to possess people to move around, how could he have fled to Albania, both after he tried to kill Harry and after Quirrell's death?

<sub>Note: Creating a Horcrux requires great magical skill, which most witches and wizards do not possess. It requires the murder of at least one individual, which most people are not willing to do. It requires unspeakably foul rituals afterward, which would turn even more people  off. It corrupts a person, body and soul. Given that there are other methods of pseudo-immortality, such as the Philosopher's Stone, a Horcrux would look very unappealing to most wizards and witches.</sub>